# What is the best practice for console logging, if jenkins plugin dependency is using slf4j?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slf4j

I am developing a Jenkins plugin which is using another library. The plugin is a wrapper, which configures a library and uses it. An idea is similar to [violation-comments-to-github-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/violation-comments-to-github-plugin). Little chances to change logging in the library. At Jenkins side I have `TaskListener.logger: PrintStream` . But the lib is logging useful info through `SLF4J`.

What are the best practices to deal with this situation? Maybe do you know some well-written plugin as an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know best what is best practice for logging, but I created [an adapter](https://github.com/vinted/slf4j-streamadapter) which does the job at least.

```
override fun perform(run: Run<*, *>, workspace: FilePath, launcher: Launcher, listener: TaskListener) {
    val logger = SLF4JOutputStreamAdapter(listener.logger, logLevel.levelInt)

    val builder = AutoMergerBuilder()
            .logger(logger) // I had implement this method in the library
}
```